# combineLatest not getting called after calling next

Tags: typescript, angular8

ProductListAltComponent.ts

Product list will display list of products in product$, once click on the product it will call onSelected method

Issue I am facing:

event is getting trigger and onSelected method is called and it calls the service method selectedProductChanged it is also get called but once aftr this .next(selectedProductId), combineLatest is not getting called

```
@Component({
  selector: 'pm-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list-alt.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ProductListAltComponent {
  pageTitle = 'Products';
  errorMessage = '';

  products$ = this.productService.productWithCategories$.pipe(
    catchError(err => {
      this.errorMessage = err;
      return EMPTY;
    })
  );
  selectedProduct$ = this.productService.selectedProduct$;
  constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }
  onSelected(productId: number): void {
    this.productService.selectedProductChanged(productId);
  }
  }
```

ProductService.ts

```
  private productSelectedSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
  productSelectedAction$ = this.productSelectedSubject.asObservable();

   selectedProduct$ = combineLatest([
    this.productWithCategories$,
    this.productSelectedAction$
  ]).pipe(
    map(([products, selectedProductId]) =>
    products.find(product => product.id === selectedProductId)
  ),
  tap(product => console.log('selectedProduct', product))
  );
  selectedProductChanged(selectedProductId: number){
    this.productSelectedSubject.next(selectedProductId);
  }
```

Product-list-alt.component.html

Here is async pipe implementation for selected

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    {{pageTitle}}
  </div>

  <div class='card-body'
       *ngIf="products$ | async as products">
    <div class='list-group'>
      <button type='button'
              class='list-group-item'
              *ngFor='let product of products'
              [ngClass]="{'active': product?.id === (selectedProduct | 
async)?.id}"
              (click)='onSelected(product.id)'>
        {{ product.productName }} ({{ product.categoryId }})
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-danger"
     *ngIf="errorMessage">
  {{errorMessage}}
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you subscribe? Post a complete minimal example as a stackblitz.

Comment: thanks so much I have missed to added $ in  selectedProduct variable

Answer (score 0):

I have missed to add $ in variable selectedProduct, So that subscribe is not called